# What does mean "Failed to retrieve current release"?

Tags: go-ethereum, synchronization

When I start with geth with light syncmode, I get the following error message:

`ERROR[date] Failed to retrieve current release          err="can't fetch trie key d0bbe1e9b7e1764fd5f966bd89e4382bb0ece1b2ca83504fb50a3806116edeae: no suitable peers available"`

What does it mean?
What should I do?

Note that after that I find peers but `admin.peers` says they are all in the handshake phase of the protocol.
I am not the only one who has encountered this problem, as shown [on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/6gfpxa/unable_to_launch_geth_in_light_mode_anymore/).

Comment: https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/issues/418

Comment: Do you mean that it is known and unsolved?

Answer (score 2):

I have had this problem before and the only way I found to get around it was to use:

> geth --syncmode "light"

With "light" being inside quotations.

For me, it immediately started synchronizing again and could get the proper release.

Comment: It is not working for me.

Comment: it's not working. i had the same error with geth --light --cache=1024 and with  geth --syncmode "light". it's just hanging there for over an hour.

Answer (score 0):

All of this is assuming you have geth in place etc and usually -v 1.7.2 or above.

**ok it is final guys! This is the solution:**

1. $ cd ~/Libary/Ethereum/geth/
2. $ mv chaindata chaindata_backup
3. $ mkdir chaindata
4. $ geth --fast --cache=1024
5. open ethereum wallet but **DO NOT** click on Launch Application.
6. Wait and if it all works fine (after 100% sync) then, remove the chaindata_backup file by doing $ ~/Libary/Ethereum/geth/chaindata_backup

Comment: Should I do that with the light chain ?

Comment: No, you should switch to regular wallet.

Comment: That's very bad advice... I cannot switch to regular wallet. My computer gets out of RAM before that.

Comment: it is not a bad advice is a computer issue you are facing. I have my wallet running just fine with a similar approach.

Comment: So, let me be clear: I am facing a computer issue, so I have to use the light syncmode. So my question is, what can I do to STILL use light syncmode BUT not having this message or at least be sure there is no problem with it. Saying "stop using light syncmode" is irrelevant. If I say I have a problem on Linux, will you say "stop using linux"? It is the same.